# Codesign failed on xamarin test recorder iOS (physical device)

Tags: testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios, recorder

I would like to record a test from a iOS device using the xamarin test recorder on a mac(el capitan OSX). I select the device and the .ipa (already signed by developers with an enterprise cert.) but i receive the following error: Codesigning failed. No codesigning identity capable of signing the application found.
I have on the machine a free apple developer account and i am able to deploy a blank project from xcode without any issue. Do i need a different account in order to re-sign the .ipa with test recorder or it should be also possible with the free account?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The free provisioning profile is tied to a specific bundle identifier, the one you created in Xcode to generate the free provisioning profile. A provisioning profile with an explicit app bundle identifier can not be used with an app that has a different bundle ID, and with the free provisioning process, you  can not create wildcard app ids for your provisioning profile. What you might try is going through that free provisioning procedure again but using the exact bundle id for the IPA you want to run in test recorder. See the [guide on creating the free provisioning profile](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/):

You should already have done steps 1-4, so start with step 5:

> 5. Plug in the iOS device you wish to deploy to and create a new blank single-view iOS project in Xcode.
> 6. Under the General > Identity section, make sure that the Bundle Identifier matches exactly the Bundle Identifier of your Xamarin.iOS app and ensure the deployment target matches or is lower than your connected iOS device. This step is extremely important, as Xcode will only create a provisioning profile with an explicit App ID:
> 7. In the Signing section, select Automatically Manage Signing and select your team from the drop down list:
> 8. The previous step will automatically generate a provisioning profile for you. You can view this, by clicking on the information icon, next to provisioning profile:
> 9. To test in Xcode, deploy the blank application to your device by clicking the run button.
> 10. Return to your IDE, with the same device plugged in, and right-click on your Xamarin.iOS project name to open the Project Options dialog. Browse to the iOS Bundle Signing section and explicitly set your signing identity and provisioning profile:

And this note in [Limitations section](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/#Limitations) is relevant:

> Provisioning Profiles created in this way will expire after one week, Signing Identities after one year. Furthermore, provisioning profiles will only be created with explicit App IDs and so you will need to follow the instructions above for every app that you wish to install.

Comment: Unfortunately,If i copy just the bundle id, without the team id, i receive an error on xcode: "failed to create provisioning profile. The app id cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again."
Stuck at step 8.

Comment: Is the bundle ID a unique string, IOW you have no App IDs associated with your Apple Team that are the same as the one you are trying to use Test recorder for?

Comment: No. I created a brand new apple dev account in order to perform some tests and evaluate Xamarin studio and Xamarin Test recorder. Also, the app that i'd like to try to record has been provided by another development team (just the .ipa).

Comment: Not sure, but it is possible that the free provisioning won't work for this scenario. However the message "failed to create provisioning profile. The app id cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again." would seem to indicate that the bundle id you are using is already registered, likely by the team that sent you the IPA. I don't know how you would get around this other than being added to their Apple dev team.

Comment: I spoke with someone from the Test Recorder team and they said the free provisioning should work as long as the app needs no entitlements (Push Notifications, iCloud, etc). They also said the iOSDeviceManager logs may be helpful. These are on your mac at path `~/.calabash/iOSDeviceManager/logs/<date>.log`